# Need help showing div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tabs and i am trying to add hover to the content inside the tabs:

```
<section class="tabs"> <input id="tab-1" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-1"

        checked="checked" type="radio"> <label for="tab-1" class="tab-label-1">About</label>
      <input id="tab-2" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-2" type="radio"> <label

        for="tab-2" class="tab-label-2">Services</label> <input id="tab-3" name="radio-set"

        class="tab-selector-3" type="radio"> <label for="tab-3" class="tab-label-3">Work</label>
      <input id="tab-4" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-4" type="radio"> <label

        for="tab-4" class="tab-label-4">Contact</label>
      <div class="clear-shadow"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-1">
          <h2>About us</h2>
          <p>Hover over me!</p>
          <h3>How we work</h3>
          <p>Info </p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-2">
          <h2>Services</h2>
          <p>Info</p>
          <h3>Excellence</h3>
          <p>Info </p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-3">
          <h2>Portfolio</h2>
          <p>Info</p>
          <h3>Examples</h3>
          <p>Info </p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-4">
          <h2>Contact</h2>
          <p>Info</p>
          <h3>Get in touch</h3>
          <p>Some Info </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

and I have content in there and when some hovers over the content i want to show this in **a box**:

```
                <div class="span6 mb-20">
                <h2 class="element-title">Toggle</h2>
                <ul id="toggle-view">
                  <li class="clearfix">
                    <h3>blah</h3>
                    <span>+</span>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="panel clearfix">
                      <p>Lorem ipsum  </p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="clearfix"> <span>+</span>
                    <h3>The Best Solution For Your Business</h3>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="panel clearfix">
                      <p>Lorem ipsum  </p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="clearfix"> <span>+</span>
                    <h3>Blah</h3>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="panel clearfix">
                      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!--end:toggle-view--> </div>
              <!--span6--> </div>
```

How would i do it? Thanks! I tried it multiple times but i had no luck, Hopefully you guys can figure it out. I am already using jquery so jquery solution will work! 
Again Thanks!

@Ohgodwhy I tried this but it doesn't work, it takes me to the top of the page:

```
<div class="content-1">
          <h2>About us</h2>
          <p>info</p>
          <h3>How we work</h3>
          <p>info</p>
        </div>
        <script>
          $('p').hover(function(){
   $('div').toggle(); 
}, function(){
   $('div').toggle();  
});
        </script>
        <div class="span6 mb-20">
                <h2 class="element-title">Toggle</h2>
                <ul id="toggle-view">
                  <li class="clearfix">
                    <h3>blah</h3>
                    <span>+</span>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="panel clearfix">
                      <p>Lorem ipsum  </p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="clearfix"> <span>+</span>
                    <h3>The Best Solution For Your Business</h3>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="panel clearfix">
                      <p>Lorem ipsum  </p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="clearfix"> <span>+</span>
                    <h3>Blah</h3>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="panel clearfix">
                      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!--end:toggle-view--> </div>
              <!--span6--> </div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with CSS :hover ?

Comment: Can we see the jQuery code that you tried? There's so much documentation on how to fire a hover event and then perform a toggle/show/hide that it's mind blowing you weren't able to figure it out given the vast resources available at your disposal (on the same site you asked your question, nonetheles)

Comment: can you please show me an example, like how would i make it so the second DIV will only display on hover. I am new to hover and html designs! Thanks and @Ohgodwhy i also tried this: http://api.jquery.com/hover/, it didn't work, the second part didn't get displayed

Comment: I'll provide you with a working example. [Please see this working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7jj4c/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Please read the updated question Thanks

Comment: @WiseGuy What browser are you testing this on?

Comment: Your selector is not specific enough for your toggle target, `$('div')` is going to target every DIV element, you need to target a class or ID, or something more specific. `$(this).next().toggle()` if you want to target the next `<h2>` or `<h3>`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `$(function(){}` on your script tag. Since you are using jQuery, you should never forgot to wrap it with `$(function(){}`

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('p').hover(function(){
           $('div').toggle(); 
        }, function(){
           $('div').toggle();  
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("mouseenter","p",function(){
        $('div').toggle();
    });
    $(document).on("mouseout","p",function(){
        $('div').toggle();
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it just takes me to the top of the page!

Comment: because you have used "$ ('div')", then the js used "toggle" in all divs of the page.
Place a class in a div that you want to use the "toggle". Like this:
$(".NameOfClass").toggle();

Comment: still no luck :(, i have multiple classes in the  <div class="span6 mb-20"> and then another class.....  i tried putting span6 mb-20 instead of div but nothing happened :(

Comment: try with hide() and show() , $(".NameOfClass").hide(), if it works, the problem is the toggle

Answer (score 0):

Try this will help you

```
$('.p').hover(

 function () {
     $('div').toggle();
 },

 function () {
     $('div').toggle();
     }
 });
```

Here your answer [`Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/KpaqD/)

Comment: No Bro! Doesn't Work, what i am trying to do is make box that will have this: <div class="span6 mb-20">
                <h2 class="element-title">Toggle</h2>
                <ul id="toggle-view">
                  <li class="clearfix">
                    <h3>blah</h3>
                    ............ and when someone goes to the content in the tabs, it should show the box on hover! I am extremely Confused..

Comment: somewhat like that, i want a box that will overlap the about us info etc... and go away on hover. i dont want it on the bottom! Thanks